# how to create http headers from scratch

Tags: python, http, http-headers, sockets

So, I made a simple socket server using python.  And now I'm trying to structure a proper http response.  However, I can't seem to find any sort of tutorial or spec that discusses how to format http responses.

Could someone point me to the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out the following article:

- [HTTP Made Really Easy: A Practical Guide to Writing Clients and Servers](http://jmarshall.com/easy/http/)

The section [Sample HTTP Exchange](http://jmarshall.com/easy/http/#sample) could help you getting started. Quoting:

> The server should respond with something like the following, sent back through the same socket:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1354

<html>
<body>
<h1>Happy New Millennium!</h1>
(more file contents)
  .
  .
  .
</body>
</html>
```

> After sending the response, the server closes the socket.

The full protocol is defined in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) if you want to get serious about this.

Answer (score 3):

[RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Comment: this RFC is the one and only true standard defining the HTTP protocol. if you are not used to RFCs, know that most standard protocols used on the internet are defined in an RFC. those documents are written in a clear and concise style and are updated (quite) regularly. there are some websites whose job is to list and collect those RFCs, along with their status/updates: you may try http://www.rfc-editor.org/ for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `urllib2` python standard library module helps you add http headers to your request.

Look in [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#headers) for an example.